# Angularjs and moments.js - angularjs not displaying the correct date

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am using Bootstrap 4 in a project. I am trying to get Angularjs to work with moments.js but am failing to do so.

I use the following HTML code:

```
<input type="date" name="somename" ng-model="theDate" max="3000-12-31" min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
```

In the mainControler.js which I created I have the following:

```
$scope.theDateToBeDisplayed = moment($scope.theDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Then when I try to display it with the following code:

```
<span ng-bind-html="theDateToBeDisplayed"></span>
```

It always returns today's date and not the one I selected in the datepicker.

> mainControler.js:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.theDateToBeDisplayed = moment($scope.theDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

});
```

> HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div>
    <input type="date" name="somename" ng-model="theDate" max="3000-12-31" min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span ng-bind-html="theDateToBeDisplayed "></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Add your HTML and controller code for better understanding.

Comment: It seems that theDate variable is equal to new Date() at your controller.

Comment: why not use angularjs date filter? e.g. `{{ theDate | date:'dd/MM/y'}}`

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. @VicJordan , done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a `function` and change the `variable` when the date in `date-picker` is changed

I added ,

- `ng-change="changeDate()"` in **HTML** which calls `changeDate` funciton when the date is changed.
- That function will assign date into `theDateToBeDisplayed` and displays in `UI`

```js
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.changeDate = function(){
       $scope.theDateToBeDisplayed = moment($scope.theDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      }   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>
            Select a date from Date picker:
            <input type="date" name="somename" ng-model="theDate" max="3000-12-31" min="1000-01-01" class="form-control" ng-change="changeDate()">
            <br>
            <br>
          <span>{{theDateToBeDisplayed}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EnYYM0ozjmsxbhXvZ3Lt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when you initialise the `theDateToBeDisplayed` variable on the scope, but my guess is it is set only once, based on an empty `$scope.theDate`, which causes moment to revert to today's date. This value is not auto-magicalle re-calculated when the date changes.

Possible solutions (I personally prefer 2):

1. When you change the `$scope.theDate`, make sure you have a watcher that sets the `$scope.theDateToBeDisplayed` again.
2. Create a filter (eg. dateFormat) that calls `moment(value).format(...)` and use:

   ```
   <span>{{theDate | dateFormat }}</span>
   ```

Comment: Hi @FrederikHeremans. As I need the date in a variable in the controller I need to go for the first option. As I am new to angularjs I don't really know what that is, and how to set up a watcher. Could you please help?

Comment: You should check out https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/. For your usecase, it will be something like `$scope.$watch('theDate', function (date) {$scope.theDateToBeDisplayed = moment(...)})`